# Do dependent product functors always reflect terminal objects?

Tags: category-theory

Let $X$ be an object of a cartesian closed category $C$ with pullbacks (and hence finite limits).

> Does the dependent product functor $\Pi_X:C/X \to C$ always reflect terminal objects? In other words, if $f$ is a morphism with codomain $X$ for which the "object of sections" of $f$ is terminal, must $f$ be an isomorphism?

It is easy to see that $f$ must at least be a split epimorphism with a unique section. Also, the above question is a generalization of the fact that the cartesian product of a family of sets is a singleton only when all of the sets in the family are themselves singletons.

Comment: I'm not certain about this. However, after fiddling for a while, I'm guessing the answer is 'no.' The only way I can come up with to prove your fact in Agda is if $X$ has decidable equality. Classically all sets have decidable equality, but not constructively. Also in homotopy type theory some types cannot have decidable 'equality', although I don't have a good example to refute the theorem there (if it can be).

Comment: Perhaps, then, a counterexample might exist in a non-Boolean presheaf topos. The base category must not be a groupoid, and the presheaf must send at least one morphism to a non-injective function for it to not be decidable. If such a counterexample turns out to exist, then please say so in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\base}{\mathsf{base}}
\newcommand{\loop}{\mathsf{loop}}
\newcommand{\transport}{\mathsf{transport}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathsf{[0]}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathsf{[1]}}
\newcommand{\2}{\mathsf{[2]}}
\newcommand{\3}{\mathsf{[3]}}
\newcommand{\Switch}{\mathsf{Switch}}
\newcommand{\fst}{\mathsf{fst}}
$
Okay, after conferring with someone who knows the homotopy angle better than I do, and some fiddling around, I've constructed [this Agda development](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/cubical/TopReflection.agda) which shows how dependent products may not reflect the terminal type.

The idea is to construct a family over the type $S^1$, which is the homotopy type of the circle with base point $\base : S^1$ and path $\loop : \base \equiv \base$. A family over this type can be given by a type $T$ and a path $P : T \equiv T$.

The key idea is that the type of sections $\prod_{c:S^1} F\ c$ is equivalent to $\sum_{t : T} \transport\ P \ t \equiv t$ (presuming that the family $F$ is equivalent to $(T, P)$ as above). That is, a section of $F$ is an element of $T$ that is fixed by $P$.

So, we can define a set $\3$ with three values, and define a path $\Switch :\3 \equiv \3$ that rotates two of the elements but leaves one fixed. This makes for a family whose sections are contractible (equivalent to the terminal object), but there are fibers of the family that are not contractible.

I'm not an expert on the categorical semantics of this stuff. The slice category presentation of this family is $\fst : (\sum_{c:S^1} F\ c) \to S^1$. The "non-boolean presheaf (pre)topos" in question is, I think, that of cubical sets (pretopos becauase Agda is predicative, and doesn't have a subobject classifier). $\fst$ is not injective because it sends $(\base, \0)$, $(\base, \1)$ and $(\base, \2)$ all to $\base$. But every section must send $\base$ to $(\base, \0)$ for the reasons discussed above.